# Codeigniter get json encoded body

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter with REST_Controller library. And so far I've been using `$this->input->post()` to get the values sent by POST request.

However, some values are sent in the body as a json encoded string, which I am not able so see with the `$this->input->post()`

Now I was able to access the json string using `file_get_contents('php://input')` but this way doesn't seem to be safe out of the box I find it highly unlikely that codeigniter wouldn't have this figured out.

So my question is: is `file_get_contents('php://input')` really the only way to access these variables in codeigniter or is there a more framework defined way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The request is being sent by [PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest), which is why CI doesn't pick it up with `post()`.

`file_get_contents('php://input')` is the only way to access HTTP PUT in code igniter; however, [this extensions](https://gist.github.com/nambok/3834056) of CI_Input will handle HTTP PUT.